# How to put layout inside another layout?

Tags: android, layout

I want to put a layout inside another layout but when I do this it gives `NullPointerException` on `relLayout.addView(squareLayout);` line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {

        RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(relIds[i][j]);
        relLayout.removeAllViews();

        RelativeLayout squareLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.square);
        relLayout.addView(squareLayout);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: We need your XML file. Also, what is that "relIds"? You should use LogCat to find out which of the 2 layouts is the one that is null.

Comment: since it's stated that  it gives `NullPointerException` on `relLayout.addView(squareLayout);` the squareLayout should be null. Have you set the setContentView, is the `square` view part of your main layout ?

Answer (score 1):

`relLayout` is not null while accessing `removeAllViews()` method. So either `findViewById()` or another thread would have set null to `relLayout` instance.

Comment: Why it should be 6 there? And if you say it is 6 then there might be an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` not a `NullPointerException`. Edit your answer and make it correct then I would withdrawl down vote.

Answer (score 0):

improper use of relIds[][] without initialization could have also caused Null pointer exception